# media query is not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I´m creating a info DIV like bootstrap´s modal. Here is my example, try to resize the result space.
https://jsfiddle.net/p1csbjy9/2/

This is the CSS code:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  #infoWindow {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1%;
  }
}

#infoWindow {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 33%;
  padding: 1%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The problem is, when I resize the window to mobile the DIV goes out of window. On desktop size all is fine.

What is wrong? maybe this is not the best way to do a modal, your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Order matters! The last rule applied takes precedence.

Comment: Something is being override it by the bootstrap stylesheet on the breakpoints. Inspect the element and resize the screen and you can see how it changes at 768px screen size

Comment: The media query should be at the bottom. It's working just fine but because the media query is on top, all of the styles within the media query will be overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap the order around so that the media query overwrites the default, like so:

```
#infoWindow {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 33%;
  padding: 1%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 670px) {
  #infoWindow {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change the order first main class then media query